# How to get content of a InlineEditorTemplate to update when its underlying PropertyValue updates

Tags: c#, wpf, workflow-foundation-4

I have a collection of objects on a custom WF4 activity that the user can edit in a designer.  I'm using a DialogPropertyValueEditor to popup a editor dialog from the PropertyGrid which can be used add\edit\remove items in the collection.

In the constructor of the DialogPropertyValueEditor I set the InlineEditorTemplate to a simple DataTemplate that contains a TextBlock that displays the number of items currently in the collection.

```
public class DataSourceFieldMappingsPropertyEditor : DialogPropertyValueEditor
{
    public DataSourceFieldMappingsPropertyEditor()
    {
      base.InlineEditorTemplate = EditorDataTemplatesResources.GetGenericListDialogDataTemplate();
    }

    public override void ShowDialog(PropertyValue propertyValue, System.Windows.IInputElement commandSource)
    {
       //display dialog
    }
}
```

The DataTemplate looks as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="editorDataTemplatesGenericListDialog">
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
             Text="{Binding Path=Value, 
             Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=GenericListConverter}, Mode=OneWay, pdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

  <sapp:EditModeSwitchButton Grid.Column="1" TargetEditMode="Dialog" />

</Grid>
```

The GenericListConverter simply looks at the collection and displays "0 Items", "5 Items" etc.

My question is:  how do I get the InlineEditorTemplate to automatically update itself when the underlying collection changes.   The DataContext for the InlineEditorTemplate is PropertyValue, but somehow the binding doesn't hook into the PropertyChanged event.

I have to click of the activity in the designer and come back to it to see the count display updated.

Comment: You know that the ModelItem wraps your Activity, all of its properties, and all type instances (except for primitives) within those properties?  And its the ModelItem that provides for property change notifications?  And if your editor isn't bound to the ModelItem it won't get these property change notifications?  Typically people don't understand all this and try to bypass the whole ModelItem thing by using `GetCurrentValue()` to get the actual instance wrapped by the ModelItem.  That can cause this issue and others, such as sync problems between the MI and the Activity.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of how the ModelItem works and I have ensured that all changes to this collection are effected through the ModelItem in the correct way.  Somehow the Textblock in the InlineEditorTemplate is not detecting the changes to the collection and refreshing itself.   I've even tried using the ModelPropertyEntryToModelItemConverter to change the DataContext to th ModelItem and binding to ModelItem.PropertyName, but it still doesn't pick up any change events....